# Trying to change columns in one table from varchar to int, and do a type lookup in another table in SQL CMD Mode on SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

The problem I'm having involves 3 tables. The first one has a primary key and some other stuff in it. We'll call it `Stuff`, with a `StuffID` as its primary key column. Let's call the second table `Things`, with `StuffID` as a foreign key, `Thing1, Thing2`, and `Thing3` as the other columns.

Currently in our production database, `Thing1, 2` and `3` are of type `varchar`.  In our development database, we added another table `ThingTypes` that has `ThingID`, `ThingName` and `ThingNumber` for columns.

So I want it to look like this:

**Stuff** table

```
StuffID (as primary key)  
Other Stuff columns
```

**Things**

```
StuffID (as foreign key)  
Thing1 (int, but corresponds to a ThingTypeID)  
Thing2 (int, corresponds to a ThingTypeID)  
Thing3 (int, corresponds to a ThingTypeID)
```

**ThingTypes**

```
ThingTypeID  
ThingTypeName  
ThingTypeNum
```

So currently, I have `varchar` names in the `Thing1,2,3` columns in the `Things` table that will correspond to the appropriate `ThingType` after the changes are made.

One other thing :). A 1 in the `ThingTypes.ThingTypeNum` column corresponds to the range of `ThingTypeNames` that will be found in the `Things.Thing1` column, a 2 corresponds to the range of `ThingTypeNames` that will be found in the `Things.Thing2` column. And the same for `Thing3`.

So I'm not sure, when I do this conversion to our production database, what the best way to do it is.  I'm using a SQL Server database, with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) so I'm able to run scripts in SSMS in SQLCMD mode.

I'm know my way around SQL, but am no expert, but I am new to database management.  Currently, I'm not able to work with a copy of the production database that I want to use to test my SQLCMD scripts against, but I'm trying to set things up ahead of time, by trying to write the scripts I need.

I've tried running a number of queries using some joins, but I can't get those to work the way I want. When converting the `varchar` names in the `Things` table to the appropriate `ThingTypeID`, I need to maintain the corresponding `StuffID`.

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Things` having a `Thing1`, `Thing2` and `Thing3` already sounds like a design flaw, and should be normalised. What happens when there's 4 things? Why store data of a "stuffs" 2nd and 3rd "thing" is it doesn't have one?

Comment: Also, what is your question here, you don't ever ask any in your "question". What is the problem you're trying to solve that you've failed to? What have you tried so far and why didn't it work? What research did you complete.

Comment: These two things " I am new to database management." should never go together" I'm not able to work with a copy of the production database that I want to use to test ".  You need to test before running scripts on your production database server.

Comment: I hereby dub this The Dr. Seuss Problem.

Comment: Don't look too deeply into the design of the tables.  I was simply trying to be very general, as I wouldn't be able to give the actual table names.  Larnu, the question is, how to utilize the ThingTypes table entries (that part I can do, by using a select from and into statement from my dev database), but then using the ThingTypeID instead of the Thing Names that are already there.  Maybe I'm not explaining it well enough.

Comment: David Brown, I understand your concerns.  I've been using, and dealt with databases for decades.  I understand what to do and what not to do to maintain the integrity of the data, and I wouldn't actually run my scripts against the production database, without testing then against a copy of the production database.  I simply was trying to get an idea of how I could make that change, when I get the database copied the way I want.  I've been playing with some select statements to see if I can pull the data that I need to make this change work.

Comment: @mdmenard You need to mention a user for them to get notified of a new comment (use @+username to do that)

Comment: Ok, so post sample table DDL, including sample data if necessary, and your attempt at the scripts.

Comment: You will need to very carefully think about how to migrate your schema. Imagine you have 2 rows in Thing where the values of Thing1 are the same. Do you consider these attributes to the specific to StuffID or can / should they be shared among all StuffID values. Until you answer answer question and consider the consequences of the different approaches there is nothing more to do.

Comment: Hi @mdmenard, I would suggest copying the data into a temporary structure, executing the alter table commands to drop the columns and re-add them (or drop the table and recreate the table), and then inserting the data you held earlier back into the table with the proper translations from varchar to int.

Comment: @Modus Tollens - Thanks for that.  I don't get on here often enough, and if no one tells me these things, I just don't know.

Comment: @mdmenard No problem, you're welcome!

Comment: So per @David Brown here is the DDL for the tables involved. This is the original setup:  CREATE TABLE Stuff (StuffID    INT   IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,  ...Other Columns not important   CONSTRAINT PK_STUFF PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StuffID ASC));  CREATE TABLE Things ( StuffID   INT   NOT NULL,  Thing1 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,  Thing2 VARCHAR(20),  Thing3 VARCHAR(20),  CONSTRAINT PK_Things PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StuffID ASC));  ALTER TABLE Things ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Things_Stuff FOREIGN KEY (StuffID)  REFFERENCES [Stuff] (StuffID) ;

Comment: Does the formatting work the same in comments <br/> but anyway

Comment: Is there a way to create a newline in comments.  But anyway, here's some data for Things, Row 1, StuffID 216, Thing1 H115, Thing2 WR 1, Thing3 WR 2, Row 2, StuffID 289, Thing1 LSTS, Thing2 WP, Thing3 WR 4, Row 3, StuffID 292, Thing1 2133 #5, Thing2 WA, Thing3 WP, ROW 4 StuffID 319, Thing1 2133 #1, Thing2 WL, Thing3 WR 1

Comment: In my development scenario, that I want to push to production, table Things looks like: 
CREATE TABLE Things ( StuffID   INT   NOT NULL,  Thing1  INT NOT NULL,  Thing2 INT,  Thing3 INT,  CONSTRAINT PK_Things PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StuffID ASC));  
ALTER TABLE Things ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Things_ThingTypes FOREIGN KEY Thing1 REFERENCES ThingTypes (ThingTypeID);
ALTER TABLE Things ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Things_ThingTypes FOREIGN KEY Thing2 REFERENCES ThingTypes (ThingTypeID);
ALTER TABLE Things ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Things_ThingTypes FOREIGN KEY Thing3 REFERENCES ThingTypes (ThingTypeID);

Comment: The new Types Table that I want to add to production looks like CREATE TABLE ThingTypes (ThingTypeID   INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
ThingTypeName   VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
ThingTypeNum    INT NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PK_ThingTypes PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ThingTypeID ASC));

Comment: And if I were to use the data that I added earlier, table ThingTypes would look something like:
Row 1, ThingTypeID 1, ThingTypeName H115, ThingTypeNum 1,
Row 2, ThingTypeID 2, ThingTypeName  LSTS, ThingTypeNum 1,
Row 3, ThingTypeID 3, ThingTypeName 2133 #5, ThingTypeNum 1,
Row 4, ThingTypeID 4, ThingTypeName 2133 #1, ThingTypeNum 1,
Row 5, ThingTypeID 5, ThingTypeName WR 1, ThingTypeNum 2,
Row 6, ThingTypeID 6, ThingTypeName  WP, ThingTypeNum 2,
Row 7, ThingTypeID 7, ThingTypeName WA, ThingTypeNum 2,
Row 8, ThingTypeID 8, ThingTypeName WL, ThingTypeNum 2,

Comment: Here are the last rows of the ThingTypes table: Row 9, ThingTypeID 9, ThingTypeName WR 2, ThingTypeNum 3,
Row 10, ThingTypeID 10, ThingTypeName  WR 4, ThingTypeNum 3,
Row 11, ThingTypeID 11, ThingTypeName WP, ThingTypeNum 3,
Row 12, ThingTypeID 12, ThingTypeName WR 1, ThingTypeNum 3,

Comment: So I want to change the Things table Thing1 column varchar values to the corresponding ThingTypeID where ThingTypeNum is 1, change the Things.Thing2 column value to the correspond ThingTypeID where ThingTypeNum is 2  in the new table once it's added.  The same for Things.Thing3.  I hope this all made sense.

Comment: Sorry for all this.  I don't post often, and should have added this to my original post (at the vary least so I could format it so it looks better).  Any help would be appreciated.